# How to Submit Form on Select Change

Tags: jquery, forms, select, submit

I have the following form. I'd like it to be submitted automatically via jQuery when the user makes a selection, without needing to press the submit button. How do I do this?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="id" id="cars">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">Toyota</option>
        <option value="2">Nissan</option>
        <option value="3">Dodge</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

adeneo, I tried your suggestion but it's still not working. Here's the complete code, anything wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#cars').on('change', function() {
                this.form.submit();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <select name="id" id="cars">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="1">Toyota</option>
                <option value="2">Nissan</option>
                <option value="3">Dodge</option>
            </select> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your form is missing an action value, which prevents submitting the form at the end. But in the mid-time you should correct this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cars').on('change', function() {
     document.forms[myFormName].submit();
  });
});
```

You can also submit a form by triggering submit button click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cars').on('change', function() {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').click();
  });
});
```

Comment: I changed it to action="page.php" which is the page's name, and it still doesn't submit the form.

Comment: I have listed two working solutions, let me know if it helped.

Comment: This is how I did it (thanks to above.) - $("#areaSelected").on("change", function () { $('#search').click(); }); I have a 'submit' button on the page called 'search' which is fired from 'onchange'.

Comment: An empty action value submits the form to the page it is on.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, this works perfectly well, and it works with or without the submit button.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="id" id="cars">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">Toyota</option>
        <option value="2">Nissan</option>
        <option value="3">Dodge</option>
    </select> 
</form>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#car').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Works for me in CoffeeScript, but I'm using `$('#car').change ->`.

Answer (score 8):

An even quicker version of the code would look something like.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="id" id="cars" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">Toyota</option>
        <option value="2">Nissan</option>
        <option value="3">Dodge</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now what we are doing is adding 
`onchange="javascript:this.form.submit()"` to any field that you want the submit action to fire on. Of course this only works on elements that support the **onchange** html property

Comment: I also think you can use this for any property that triggers an action

Comment: There's not a lot of reason to use jQuery for this, I use this method, unless someone forces me to use jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

Just use assistance of JavaScript.

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
    ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old (and already answered), but none of the answers was quite as flexible as I wanted, so below is the solution I ended up with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#cars').change(function() {
     var parentForm = $(this).closest("form");
     if (parentForm && parentForm.length > 0)
       parentForm.submit();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

even you can do this one:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="id" id="cars">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">Toyota</option>
    <option value="2">Nissan</option>
    <option value="3">Dodge</option>
</select> 
<input id='submit' type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#cars').on('change', function() {
     $('#submit').click();

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is create hidden submit button and click it on change event .

```
 <select name="id" onchange="javascript:$('#submit').click();">
 <option value="0">Please Select Web Site</option>
 <option value="1">------</option>
 <option value="2">-------</option>
 </select>
 <button id="submit" class="hidden" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My code to submit a form with jquery without a submit button with the change event on a select element:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#select123").on("change", function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```